# Fedora 25 Linux - permission denied on cd /var/lib/pgsql

Tags: file-permissions, fedora-25

this is my first time posting on stack overflow (been lurking for quite some time).

I have been trying to solve this problem for a few hours but for the life of me cannot figure it out. I am brand new to Linux and Postgresql and have been a windows guy all of my life so things are pretty confusing to me right now.

Currently I am trying to figure out why I cannot get into the /var/lib/pgsql folder. I need to get in there so I can edit a config file. Whenever I try to get in there I get

bash: cd: pgsql: Permission denied

I have also tried sudo rm -r pgsql and re-creating it but that doesn't seem to work either. Apparently sudo cd isn't a real thing either so... not really sure where to go from here. Not really sure why I don't have permissions by default to this folder.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/PostgreSQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`/var/lib/pgsql` is a home directory of user pgsql. Almost all home directories have '`0700`' access mode.

```
ls -lah  /var/lib/ | grep pgsql
drwx------. 1 postgres       postgres        282 лис 26 17:05 pgsql
```

Try use sudo to emulate postgresql user login:

```
sudo -u postgres -i
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That got me into the folder and I can modify the config now.

Comment: Don't mention it! But your question not conforms with stackoverflow conventions